# Keeping the Insertion Cursor on a readonly Tkinter Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am using the tkinter module in my python code to create my gui for an simple app I am creating. I was wondering if it is possible to keep the **insertion cursor** visible even when the the state on my entry widget is set to "*readonly*". I want the user to still see where the insertion cursor is in the text but not be able to edit the text directly using the keyboard.

---

**Note:**

When I say **Insertion Cursor** I don't mean the normal mouse cursor/pointer but the flashing bar which shows up on text which you can edit. I'm not sure what the proper name for it is... Below is an example of what I mean (the black bar in the Entry)

[image: Example of insertion cursor]

---

I have tried setting the 'insertwidth' and other *insertion cursor* config options in the Entry widget to see if the cursor was perhapes just hidden but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the entry widget readonly, you could block all keyboard events on the widget, which makes typing in it impossible:

```
entry.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. It also means I can still bind a function to a key press and return "break" in the function if I don't want that key to show.

Comment: Yeah, returning `"break"` tells tkinter to stop processing the event, so the normal action for the event (for example, inserting an `a` when you press the a-key) isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to disable the `Entry` and change its `disabledbackground`. Example:

```
entry.config(disabledbackground ="white",state="disabled")
```

So , assuming that you are using `python 3` ,your code can be like:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ent = Entry(root)
ent.config(disabledbackground ="white",state="disabled")
ent.place(x=0,y=0)
mainloop()
```

You entry will look like:

[image]

### Edit:

As the question is edited, so I will suggest you to use `bind`. Unlike `@fhdrsdg`'s answers , you can use the bind function in a more easy way:

```
ent.bind("<Key>", "pass")
```

So , you can say that your complete code is:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ent = Entry(root)
ent.bind("<Key>", "pass")
ent.pack()
mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes that would make the background look normal but the problem is that the **insertion cursor** doesn't display when the state is "disabled" or "readonly". I was wondering if it is possible to force the insertion cursor to show even on those states. The above answer has provided an alternative solution to my problem though.

Comment: @SamuelT Check this image. Its very simple. You can try running the code.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what I mean. Sorry my explanation isn't very good :) When I say insertion cursor I mean the black bar in the entry widget. Check out my edited question.

Comment: Besides simpler the code, is their any advantage to using "pass" over "break"? I think I will use the "break" method as I can return it from a function to stop specific key presses. Thanks anyway.